# trying to plot a graph but comes back empty

Tags: python, function, graph, valueerror

hi trying to plot the graph of the results from a while loop but keeps returning an empty graph and saying there is a value error

```
  #create function f(n)
  def f(n):
if (n % 2)==0:
    return n/2
else:
    return (3*n+1)/2
  #loop funtion  
q=63
while q != 1:
q=f(q)

 #plot the function   
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

i=np.linspace(0,10,3)

plt.plot(q,i)
plt.show()
```

Comment: are you sure that is an empty graph and not a single point graph? check it with `plot(q, i, '+')`

Comment: its not a single point im not sure whats going on

Comment: `q` is a single value, `i` not. You should describe by words what are you trying to do, what do you expect from your code, what is `f` and why you need a `while` [and format your code properly -> use the triple ` to enclose a block of code]

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to properly indent the code as it's is easier to interpret :)

The reason you got value error was because the dimensions of your x and y values are dissimilar. While for x you were passing a variable of size 1, for y you are passing an array of size 3. Furthermore, when using matplotlib's plot function, it's advised to specify the attributes of the plot function which determine the kind of plot you want (otherwise it can output an empty plot). I have inputted example values in the revised code below.

Hope this helps in achieving your main goal of plotting the function!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
def f(n):

  if (n % 2)==0:
     return n/2
  else:
     return (3*n+1)/2
  #loop function  
q=63
while (q != 1):
   q=f(q)

 #plot the function   
i=np.linspace(0,10,3)

#Here i is an array of type float of size 3, so you need to pick one of the
#values in i to plot with the value of q(which is a float variable of size 1)
plt.plot(q, i[2], color='green', marker='o')        
plt.show()
```